# Next.js Pages folder: not caching javascript bundles. it loads bundled node_modules everytime I reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is a site that needs the user to log in,
We have 3mb of node_modules loading every time the page loads.

I know that it should have tree shaking but my first step is to try and solve why it is not caching that huge JS file.

[image]